# Spring Cloud Config with AWS Secrets Manager or Parameter Store

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to configure a Spring Cloud Config Server to use either AWS Secrets Manager or Parameter Store. I've been hitting brick wall after brick wall.

This is my latest `pom.xml`:

```
 <dependencies>
    <!-- Config server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ... a bunch of stuff that doesn't matter ...
    <!-- AWS - fairly sure I don't want all of these -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependencies>
```

And my application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: aws-secretsmanager
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        aws-secretsmanager:
          region: us-west-1
          default-label: latest
```

And this is lengthy, but it's what happens when I run it:

```
2023-10-19T15:23:54.915-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] c.t.s.SpringCloudConfigServerApplication : Starting SpringCloudConfigServerApplication using Java 17.0.8 with PID 54547 (/Users/jpl/Work/Research/SpringCloudConfigServer/target/classes started by jpl in /Users/jpl/Work/Research/SpringCloudConfigServer)
2023-10-19T15:23:54.916-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] c.t.s.SpringCloudConfigServerApplication : The following 1 profile is active: "aws-secretsmanager"
2023-10-19T15:23:55.281-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-10-19T15:23:55.281-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-19T15:23:55.288-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-10-19T15:23:55.294-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-10-19T15:23:55.295-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-19T15:23:55.298-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 0 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2023-10-19T15:23:55.386-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=50679c0d-1bc9-3d1c-bef4-1fae13e98217
2023-10-19T15:23:55.549-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2023-10-19T15:23:55.552-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-19T15:23:55.552-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.13]
2023-10-19T15:23:55.593-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-19T15:23:55.594-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 657 ms
2023-10-19T15:23:55.775-05:00  WARN 54547 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-10-19T15:23:55.777-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-10-19T15:23:55.785-05:00  INFO 54547 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-19T15:23:55.795-05:00 ERROR 54547 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles aws-secretsmanager are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not even close to getting this to work, and I still haven't gotten to the point of being able to specify my AWS credentials.

I'm using IntelliJ, which is pretty good helping me write my application.yml file, but it flat out doesn't recognize anything related to specifying AWS credentials. I don't know if I just don't have the right dependencies or what is wrong.

Does anyone have an actual working application that uses AWS anything with Spring Cloud Config?

Comment: If you're using spring v3, the setup is a little different now https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#loading-external-configuration-2. Your current setup looks right at a glance for spring v2.

Comment: Why not use the Offiical AWS SDK For Java V2 Secret manager API within a Spring Boot project. It works fine.

Comment: I think I have version issues. The starter project used spring boot 3.1.5, which may not be supported by some of the other tools needed. I've tried 2.7.x, but I'm not getting any further.